# Bootstrap custom 36 column grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

So I have looked all over the web and thei site and can't quite figure it out.

I want to create a custom grid in Bootstrap. The container should be `5760px` and have 36 columns with `20px` gutters. I know this is ridiculously large. but what I am trying to do is essentially have 3 12 column grids (each `1920px` wide) side by side.

I've tried the custom build for Bootstrap but I don't really understand the container / grid system I guess. Also I am using `Sass` as opposed to `Less`. So that presents another twist.

If I could just get the css and by pass all the `Sass` / `Less` stuff that would be great.

Comment: why not have 3x 4-col in 1 row and in each of them have 12-col ...

Comment: Youre looking for nested grid. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: Hi there Pogrindis. Thanks for the response but not quite. The 3x 4-col answer does not address the width problem of the container. And in regards to nested grid... I am not, I want 1 grid, 5760px wide with 36 columns each with 20 px gutters. That's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so im going out on a limb here, but if you're working with bootstrap and you want to configure the basics so much.

What you can do is download a customized version of it.

Take a look here : [Boostrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/customize)

Here you will be able to customize the amount of columns you wish to work with : [Custom Grid Count](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=4d6d2ba01863b3606e27#grid-system)
And you will also be able to select the container size. : [Container Width](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=4d6d2ba01863b3606e27#container-sizes)

Along with all the features of bootstrap.. And all from bootstrap themselves.

Once you have all your fields filled in and edited to your spec, scroll to the bottom and 'compile' it!

As an answer goes its really the best i think I can offer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but I've already tried that ("I've tried the custom build for Bootstrap but I don't really understand the container / grid system I guess. Also I am using Sass as opposed to Less. So that presents another twist.").

Comment: The container I got, I believe. It's the grids I don't understand, with all the @ media queries.